# Two subsets with homeomorphic parts of boundaries

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $U$ be an open subset. Denote by $\simeq$ "being homeomorphic". Assume that $A, B\subseteq X$ are such that

$$U\subseteq A\subseteq\overline{U}$$
$$U\subseteq B\subseteq\overline{U}$$
$$A\backslash U \simeq B\backslash U$$

So $A\backslash U$ is not really a boundary of $A$ but a piece of boundary that belongs to $A$.

**Question:** Does it follow that $A\simeq B$?

I'm pretty sure that there will be some pathological $X$ that doesn't satisfy it. So here are some variants I am interested in as well:

- Both $A\backslash U$ and $B\backslash U$ are closed in $X$
- $X$ is Hausdorff or metrizable or even finite dimensional real space
- $U$ is connected
- $\overline{U}$ is compact

Comment: But let $U$ the unit disk, $A = U \cup \{1\}$, $B = U \cup \{1,-1\}$. You can make lots of examples in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\partial U$ is a smooth submanifold by including non-homeomorphic parts of $\partial U$ into $A$ resp. $B$.

Comment: Hmm? $\partial A = \partial U = \partial B$ in that example. Do you perhaps want $A\setminus U \simeq B \setminus U$?

Comment: @DanielFischer My bad, of course I was thinking about $A\backslash U$. Damn, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not follow. A simple example is

$$U = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \lvert z\rvert < 1\},\quad A = U \cup \{0\}, \quad B = U \cup \{1\}.$$

An example where $\partial U$ is a smooth manifold: Let $U = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ and

\begin{align}
A &= U \cup \bigl\{e^{i\varphi} : \varphi \in [-1,1] \cup \{\pi/2\} \cup [\pi - 1, \pi + 1] \cup \{3\pi/2\}\bigr\}, \\
B &= U \cup \bigl\{e^{i\varphi} : \varphi \in [-1,1] \cup \{3/2, 2\} \cup [\pi - 1, \pi + 1]\bigr\}.
\end{align}

A putative homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ would induce a homeomorphism of $U$ and thus it is impossible that it switches the order of the parts on $\partial U$, but in $B$ the two singleton components are neighbours, while in $A$ they aren't.

In both examples, $X = \mathbb{C}$ is an extremely nice topological space (a Riemann surface), $U$ is connected with compact closure, and $A\setminus U$ resp. $B\setminus U$ are also compact.

Comment: Wow, this actually is pretty amazing example! I'll try to figure out details before accepting this answer but it seems to be correct. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably easier to write down a rigorous proof if you let $U = \{ z : 1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2\}$, and have $A$ one arc and one point on each of the two boundary circles, and $B$ one arc on each boundary circle, and two points on one of the boundary circles. Then a homeomorphism can't move one point from the boundary circle across the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 3/2$.

Comment: So, I think that this is correct. Thank you again. One more question (assuming you still have strength :D ). Do you think it is still possible to find a counterexample if we additionally assume that $A\backslash U$ is connected? I'm trying to add more and more assumptions such that my case still satisfies them and that they will finally produce such homeomorphism.

Comment: It probably is possible if we move to higher dimensions and play with not simply connected boundaries.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Let $U$ be the slit annulus $\{ z : 1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2\}\setminus (1,2)$. Let $A\setminus U$ be an arc on one of the boundary circles, and let $B\setminus U = [1,2]$. Actually, it is even easier to see that $A$ and $B$ aren't homeomorphic here, $A$ is simply connected, but $B$ isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2,$ $U=V\cup W$ $V=(0,1)\times (0,1) ,W=(-1,0)\times (-1,0), K=\left\{\left( 0,\frac{1}{2} \right)\right\}, L=\{ (0,t): 0<t<1 \wedge t\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then take $A=V\cup L\cup W, B=V\cup K\cup W.$

Comment: My bad, I actually formulated the question incorrectly. I was thinking about $A\backslash U$, not $\partial A$.